# Why am I getting an email notification when users go to my site?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am developing a site and noticed in testing, I'll get an email ping when going to the URL. Basically what is returned is a blank notification.

[image]

I suspect it's something to do with what I entered in the action field?

```
<form id="frmContact" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
```

Also I entered the php script right above the html declaration tag...

```
<?php

$to = "17antonio.ortiz@gmail.com"; 
$from = $_REQUEST['email']; 
$name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
$headers = "From: $from"; 
$subject = "You have a message sent from your site"; 

$fields = array(); 
$fields{"name"} = "name"; 
$fields{"email"} = "email"; 
$fields{"comments"} = "comments";

$body = "Here is what was sent:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

$send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Any insight will be appreciated!

P.S. Is there anyway to make the text in the email flush left? :) Looks a little funny centered!

Comment: What are you asking? The very first thing your page does is send an email, and since there's no content, the email is blank. Why is this a surprise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php code is being executed every single time the page is loaded. What you probably want instead is to run the php code only after the form is posted:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
  // paste all your php code to send the email here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your script is executed every time the page is requested. What you want to do is set some sort of condition. For example, you should check if a POST request was made to this page and only then execute the PHP code (this is if you submit the form data via POST). See an example [here](http://develop-a-website.com/simple-php-contact-form/).

Answer (score 0):

You should check first that is form posted or you. You can check it by checking any form field is set or not

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))
{
    $to = "17antonio.ortiz@gmail.com"; 
    $from = $_REQUEST['email']; 
    $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 
    $headers = "From: $from"; 
    $subject = "You have a message sent from your site"; 
    $fields = array(); 
    $fields{"name"} = "name"; 
    $fields{"email"} = "email"; 
    $fields{"comments"} = "comments";

    $body = "Here is what was sent:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .=                 sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); }

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
?>
```